# Java API to get the start and end detail of Daylight saving time for a particular timezone for a year

Tags: java, datetime, calendar, timezone, jodatime

So I am using [`getAvailableZoneIds()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html#getAvailableZoneIds()) method under [`java.time.ZoneId`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/ZoneId.html) to fetch a list of available timezones.

I wanted to know if there is a way by which for a specific timezone eg- “America/Chicago” , I can find out the starting and ending date time detail of daylight saving time for a year.
Like when does it start and ends.
Gone though various classes including ZoneId ,ZonedDateTime, ZoneOffset,TimeZone available in java but not able to find any way by which I can fetch this details.

I tried the below code and gives output mentioned below

```
    ZoneId zoneId= ZoneId.of("America/Sao_Paulo");
    ZoneRules zoneRules = zoneId.getRules();
    System.out.println("previous Transition of DST ==>  " + zoneRules.previousTransition(Instant.now()));
    System.out.println("next Transition of DST ==>  " + zoneRules.nextTransition(Instant.now()));
```

Output:

```
previous Transition of DST ==>  Transition[Overlap at 2019-02-17T00:00-02:00 to -03:00]
next Transition of DST ==>  Transition[Gap at 2019-11-03T00:00-03:00 to -02:00]
```

But I need to find out for a particular year , what time it starts and what time does it end .

Comment: i think you can do the trick with https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZoneId.html and https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html  ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("America/Chicago"); should give you what you need.

Comment: i think ZoneId class in Java does not have any method to give start and end details of Day Light saving time (DST ) for a particular timezone.

Comment: your code says "America/Sao_Paulo" instead of “America/Chicago”

Comment: @GeorgeWeekson Just took another timeZone example while testing some code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a particular year, you can give [`ZoneRules`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html) a year as part of specifying a moment. For any given moment, you can ask [next](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#nextTransition(java.time.Instant)) or [previous](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/ZoneRules.html#previousTransition(java.time.Instant)) [`ZoneOffsetTransition`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/zone/ZoneOffsetTransition.html).

Here is example code for [`Europe/Sofia`](https://time.is/Sofia) time zone.

```
ZoneId zoneSofia = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Sofia" );
ZoneRules zoneRules = zoneSofia.getRules();

// Pick a moment, arbitrarily.
ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.of( 2019 , 10 , 15 , 10 , 0 , 0 , 0 , zoneSofia );
// Is DST in effect at that moment?
boolean isDst = zoneRules.isDaylightSavings( zdt.toInstant() );

// When are the closest offset transitions, previous (in the past), and next (in the future).
ZoneOffsetTransition previousTransition = zoneRules.previousTransition( zdt.toInstant() );
ZoneOffsetTransition nextTransition = zoneRules.nextTransition( zdt.toInstant() );

// When is the next transition happening in UTC? In Sofia time?
Instant nextTransitionInstant = nextTransition.getInstant();  // An `Instant`` is always in UTC, by definition.
ZonedDateTime nextTransactionZdt = nextTransitionInstant.atZone( zoneSofia ); // Same moment, same point on the timeline, different wall-clock time.
boolean isDstAfterTransition = zoneRules.isDaylightSavings( nextTransactionZdt.toInstant() );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "zone = " + zoneSofia );
System.out.println( "zdt: " + zdt );
System.out.println( "isDst: " + isDst );
System.out.println( "previousTransition = " + previousTransition );
System.out.println( "nextTransition = " + nextTransition );
System.out.println( "nextTransitionInstant = " + nextTransitionInstant );
System.out.println( "nextTransactionZdt = " + nextTransactionZdt );
System.out.println( "isDstAfterTransition = " + isDstAfterTransition );
```

> zone = Europe/Sofia
>
> zdt: 2019-10-15T10:00+03:00[Europe/Sofia]
>
> isDst: true
>
> previousTransition = Transition[Gap at 2019-03-31T03:00+02:00 to +03:00]
>
> nextTransition = Transition[Overlap at 2019-10-27T04:00+03:00 to +02:00]
>
> nextTransitionInstant = 2019-10-27T01:00:00Z
>
> nextTransactionZdt = 2019-10-27T03:00+02:00[Europe/Sofia]
>
> isDstAfterTransition = false

We can see than the next transition in `Europe/Sofia` happens at the moment that *would* look like 4 AM while 3 hours ahead of UTC:

```
nextTransition = Transition[Overlap at 2019-10-27T04:00+03:00 to +02:00]
```

…but since we are doing a [Daylight Saving Time (DST)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) “Fall back”, we turn the hands of the clock back to 3 AM to be 2 hours ahead of UTC:

```
nextTransactionZdt = 2019-10-27T03:00+02:00[Europe/Sofia]
```

And we can see with `isDstAfterTransition` that at that moment we are no longer in DST.

Notice how, on this date of the 27th, the people of the the Sofia region experience the hour of 3-4 AM *twice*. This first 3-4 AM hour is at 3 hours ahead of UTC. The second 3-4 AM hour is at 2 hours ahead of UTC.

And, this means the day of the 27th runs 25 hours long rather than 24.

Comment: Your code example was improperly formatted. I think I fixed it but double-check my changes. This site uses Markdown. Lines of code should be indented with four SPACE characters.

Comment: @BasilBourque Thanks for response. One small query which i have is for Europe region, i believe DST starts on Last Sun of Oct and ends on Last Sun Of March. But if we check for the current date (15th Oct 2019) for "Europe/Sofia", if it's in DST or not , it gives TRUE. Same way if i check for any date after 27th Oct , it gives false. So I am missing some basics here. Could you please help me to get this concept clear for me.

Comment: `ZoneOffsetTransition nextNextTransition =zoneRules.nextTransition(nextTransition.getInstant());` , `System.out.println("Next transition after that at: " +nextNextTransition.getInstant().atZone(zone))` @BasilBourque Similar way above code gives next transition at 2020-03-29T04:00+03:00[Europe/Sofia] , after which if i check for 30th March , it gives DST as true.

Comment: @GeorgeWeekson Thanks for all the response and answer and apologies for the wrong tagging. Will go through the doc to find the details.

Comment: @GeorgeWeekson After do some experimenting with your code to clarify my understanding, I thought my rearrangement of your code might help others, So I replaced your arrangement with mine. And I added some explanatory text. If you feel I have hijacked your Answer, revert the changes and I'll post my own Answer.

Comment: @BasilBourque it will help indeed.